# how to access tableviewcell accessory detail when using a static cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard, uitableview

I am using several static cells in a tableviewcontroller.

Each cell has a detail accessory.  What method can I use in the tableviewcontroller to perform logic based on the click of a detail accessory?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make your tableView delegate implement the following method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just drag from the cell to the view and it gives you a cell and accessory object.